# Como poderia diminuir meu código?

Tags: javascript

Olá Sou iniciante então não manjo muito disso mas estava praticando e percebi que não conseguia colocar quebra de linha no document.write, então decidi fazer dessa maneira aí porém sinto que fiz errado. Como poderia diminuir?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulário de compra</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:wheat ;
                color:black ;
                font:oblique 22pt roboto;
                }
            h1{
                color:black;
                font:normal calibri;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
<body>
    <h1>Valor da Compra</h1>
    <p>
        <script>
            var n1= Number(prompt('Quantos fardos de refrigerante de 2 litros?'))
            var n2= Number(prompt('Quantos kilos de carne?'))
            var n3= Number(prompt('Quantas sacolas de pão?'))
            var jun1= n1*12
            var jun2= n2*10
            var jun3= n3*3.5
            var tot= jun1+jun2+jun3
            var res1=document.write('Preço do refrigerante:'+ jun1.toLocaleString('pt-br', {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'}))
        
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <script> 
            var res2=document.write('Preço da carne:'+jun2.toLocaleString('pt-br', {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'}))
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <script>
            var res3=document.write('Preço do pão:'+jun3.toLocaleString('pt-br', {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'}))
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <script>
            var res4=document.write('Preço da comida:' + tot.toLocaleString('pt-br', {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'}))
        </script>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dica não misture código com markup (HTML) e muito menos estilo(css), deixe que cada um faça o seu do jeito que tem que fazer.

> Use [Funções](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) onde você puder para evitar repetição de pedaços de código que fazem a mesma coisa, isso tornará o seu código mais simples e fácil de ler
>
> Use a [Interpolação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) onde for necessário para concatenar algum texto/string com o valor de alguma variável

Siga alguns princípios de programação, como [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#:%7E:text=The%20KISS%20principle%20states%20that,unnecessary%20complexity%20should%20be%20avoided.&text=The%20term%20%22KISS%20principle%22%20was%20in%20popular%20use%20by%201970.), procure manter sempre o seu código limpo e reutilizável em qualquer parte do teu programa.

```js
// Escreva uma função que atualize o HTML de um elemento passsado
function updateElement(id, value){
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
}

// Escreva uma função que se ocupe de perguntar o valor e retornar o mesmo já multiplicado pelo fator passado
function askPrice(question, multiplierFactor){
  const n = Number(prompt(question));
  return n * multiplierFactor;
}

// Pergunte os preços usando a função criada anteriormente
const preccoRefri = askPrice('Quantos fardos de refrigerante de 2 litros?', 12);
const precoCarne = askPrice('Quantos kilos de carne?', 10);
const precoPao = askPrice('Quantas sacolas de pão?', 3.5);

// Calcule o valor total
const total = preccoRefri + precoCarne + precoPao;

// Defina o formato da moeda uma única vez e salve em uma variável para ser reultilizado mais tarde
const format = {style:'currency', currency: 'BRL'};

// Atualize seus elementos
updateElement('precoPao', `Preço pão: ${precoPao.toLocaleString('pt-br', format)}`);
updateElement('precoCarne', `Preço carne: ${precoCarne.toLocaleString('pt-br', format)}`);
updateElement('precoRefrigerante', `Preço refrigerante: ${preccoRefri.toLocaleString('pt-br', format)}`);
updateElement('precoTotal', `Preço comida: ${total.toLocaleString('pt-br', format)}`);
```

```html
<p id="precoPao"></p>
<p id="precoRefrigerante"></p>
<p id="precoCarne"></p>
<hr />
<p id="precoTotal"></p>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ainda não conheço muito de javascript mas vou tentar aprender tudo oq vc informou.

Answer (score 0):

No caso, pelo que compreendi, você quer exibir todos os valores no html quebrando as linhas.

Como está no seu:

```
document.write('Preço da comida')
```

Tente colocar:

```
document.write('<br>Preço da comida')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a template string https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

ai para quebrar a linha usar \n